# How to retrieve the value of uniqueidentifier generated while insert in Delphi ADO?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, uniqueidentifier

Suppose I generate the PK for my SQL Server DB table with the help of `newid()` function. In `Java` I can do something like this:

```
...
String query = "DECLARE @newGuid uniqueidentifier "+
"SET @newGuid = newid() "+
"INSERT INTO myTable(id, stringval) "+
"VALUES (@newGuid, "Hello") "+
"SELECT uid FROM @newGuid";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
String uid = rs.getString("uid");
```

But when I try to make that with Delphi+ADO I get stuck cause `ADO` can either get data from DB (`Open` method of `AdoQuery`) or put data to DB (`ExecSQL` method). So I can't insert new value to the table and get the parameter value afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve this problem atleast in two ways.

1. You can put both of your SQL queries into one string (just like you have in your example) and call `TADOQuery.Open` or `TADOQuery.Active := True`. it doesn't matter that you have `INSERT` statement there as long as query returns something.
2. You can define parameter's direction as pdOutput in `ADOQuery.Parameters` collection and read value of that parameter after executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating `@newGuid` as if it was a table. Your last row  in the query should be:

```
SELECT @newGuid as uid
```